# jasmine $timeout triggers ui-router resolve elsewhere

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I have a jasmine test for a directive that flushes a $timeout in order to test certain code within the directive. At another point in the application, I have a ui-router handling navigation with the following resolve

```
 $stateProvider
    .state('home', {
        url: '/home',
        component: 'home',
        resolve: {
            myservice: "myservice",
            myItems: function(myservice) {
                return myservice.resource.query().$promise;
            }

        }
    })
```

The directive is in the same angular module as this home component (the directive is nested inside of the component).

Whenever the test runs for the directive and $timeout.flush() is called, I get an 'error: unexpected request' with the url of the query. This is happening even though the directive and that component shouldn't be associated. A quick fix is to just add in an $httpBackend to fix it, but this shouldn't be happening, and as more things are added I think the problem will be replicated.

I have confirmed that a) it is that resolve function that is triggering the request, b) I have checked the $state in the directive tests but it returns an empty string so I don't think its trying to set up the home state c) There is no code in the directive test referencing this component or anything like that

If it helps, the setup code in the test is as follows:

```
 scope = $rootScope.$new();
 var element = $compile('..../*doesnt include home component at all*/......')(scope);
    scope.$digest();
    $timeout.flush();
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay..... after reading the following https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/212 for way too long, the appropriate solution is:

```
beforeEach(module(function($urlRouterProvider) {
    $urlRouterProvider.deferIntercept();
}))
```

The aforementioned resolve that was the problem is called in the state that $urlRouterProvider.otherwise() points to. By deferring that we prevent the home state from being realized and that resolve from triggering the resource call